# How to return class name from a method ? Also how to find Class of an given object?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to return a .class file or Activity name from a method of a class. So that i can call that Activity in Intent method. It is like :-

```
public class MonthCall {
    public Class getobj(View v)
    {
        Class c;
        if(v.getId()== R.id.btnjan)
        {
            c = Jan.class;
        }
        else if(v.getId()== R.id.btnfeb)
        {
            c = Feb.class;
        }
        else
        {
            c = Diary.class;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Now, I want to use these returned value for calling activities as Many of buttons are common in various Activity, so that it will be calling the same Activity.

```
    public class Month extends Activity {
        MonthCall monthCall;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.month);
        }
        public void monthclick(View view)
        {
            Class cr;
            cr = monthCall.getobj(view);
            Intent i = new Intent(this,cr.getClass());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

How can I implement above in right way? Help me to get the solution soon?

Comment: why you want to get class name you can pass explicitly  class name in Intent.

Comment: Yes, but 12 buttons are same in 13 Activity (including Jan to Dec itself so that one can go from jan to march and march to other month) and if in this way we can do then no need to write same code in all 12 Activity. Or any other option ? please guide me !

Comment: You should create one Utility Class for calling Activity so you can only pass values in it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof` keyword of java to achieve this.

Just for an example see below example:

```
String s = "WhichClassInstanceIm";

if (s instanceof java.lang.String) 
{
    System.out.println("String class");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Unknown");
}
```